# jQuery sidebar menu backdrop wont hide click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jQuery sidebar menu show on click got something problem after sidebar hide, the overlay (.backdrop) wont hide.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfehs6bg/69/)

HTML

```
<li class="topHeaderMenu leftMenu listMenu" id="open"><div   class="listMenuDiv"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></div></li>

<div class="backdrop"></div>

<div class="sidebar">
  content
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#open').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
$(".backdrop").toggle();
})

$(document).click(function(e)
{
    var sidebar = $(".sidebar, #open");

    if(!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        $('#open').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
        sidebar.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
p {
text-align: center;
}

ul
{
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-120%);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100vh;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 8;
}

.active
{
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.backdrop
{
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
z-index: 7;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

So the problem is, after sidebar hide the .backdrop not hide. What I want is hide when click outside sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you are removing the 'active' class but not hiding your backdrop div. Please use below code

```
$('#open').click(function()
    {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('actives');
        $(".backdrop").toggle();
    })

    $(document).click(function(e)
    {
        if($(".sidebar.actives").length > 0)
        {
            var sidebar = $(".sidebar, #open");

            if(!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0)
            {
                $('#open').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
                sidebar.removeClass('actives');
        $(".backdrop").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```